# Styling multiple links in php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have some php which works on my site to style a link. However, when I try to use the same code to style other links in a different way, it breaks my site.

For example I have:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
echo '<style>
.events-dashboard1 {background-color: green;}
</style>';
}
```

This works but when I try to duplicate like so:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
echo '<style>
.post-job1.post-event1 {background-color: #e5f25c; color: white
!important;}
</style>';
}
```

The site breaks. I've investigate and found that using multiple classes like that doesn't work. But if I repost the same php code just with 1 class, it breaks. Tried altering the format - nothing.

Html:

```
<div id="adminmenuwrap">
<ul id="adminmenu">
<li class="wp-first-item wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp- 
menu-open menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top. 
first" id="menu-dashboard">
<a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item 
wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open menu-top menu- 
top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-first">
<div class="wp-menu- 
arrow"><div></div>
</div><div class='wp-menu-image dashicons-before 
dashicons-dashboard'><br /></div>
<div class='wp-menu- 
name'>Dashboard</div>
</a>
<ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'>
<li class='wp-submenu-head' aria- 
hidden='true'>Dashboard</li>
            <li class="wp-first-item current">.
                <a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item current" 
aria- current="page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='update-core.php'>Updates 
<span class='update-plugins count-37'><span class='update. 
count'>37</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="jobs-dashboard1"><a 
href='https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/' class="jobs. 
dashboard1">Jobs</a></li>
            <li class="post-job1"><a 
href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-a-job/' class="post-job1">Post A 
Job</a></li>
            <li class="events-dashboard1"><a 
 href='https://adsler.co.uk/your-events-dashboard/' class="events. 
 dashboard1">Events</a></li>
            <li class="post-event1"><a 
href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/' class="post-event1">Post 
An Event</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

So now I have four links, two of which I can't style, the other two are styles by above code and the following code. One for each:

```
function custom_admin_css() { echo ' <style> .jobs- 
dashboard1 { background-color: green; } </style>'; } 
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do NOT use periods in style names. You can use a period, but it has to be escaped such as .this\.is\.my\.bad\.idea\.for\.a\.class\.name (see all those escapes). Instead, use something like underscore_names or camelCaseNames.

Comment: What, like`_post-job`?  Instead of`.post-job`?Thanks

Comment: No. The . at the beginning indicates that it is a class name, not an ID. The dots in the middle of the name that you used cause a problem. .post-job1.post-event1 needs to be typed as .post-job1\.post-event1.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work.... :-(

Comment: That wasn't a solution to the entire problem. There are MANY problems with your code. I was just pointing out one of them. The root of the problem is that you apparently don't understand CSS or functions and you are trying to use both. The solution is to read up on CSS and read up on functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all of your styles under the same  tag.  It appears you are trying to use the same function twice, which you cannot do.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
echo '<style>
.events-dashboard1 {background-color: green;}
.post-job1, .post-event1 {background-color: #e5f25c; color: white
!important;}

/* Any other CSS you have put here */

</style>';
}
```

Ultimately, what you should do, is create a CSS file.  Put your CSS in it.  Then enqueue it.  Like this.

**admin-styles.css**

```
.events-dashboard1 {background-color: green;}
.post-job1, .post-event1 {background-color: #e5f25c; color: white
!important;}

/* the rest of your CSS */
```

**enqueue the file**

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-css', '/path/to/file/admin-styles.css');
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, if only I knew were to start. Oh website woes (and alliteration) :-)

Comment: But why won't it let me duplicate?  2 x `add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
echo '<style>
.events-dashboard1 {background-color: green;}
</style>';
}`?

Comment: Because you can't use the same function name twice.  You are using "my_custom_css" twice.  You can't do that.  Each function can only be called once.  But you only need one function anyways, you just need to put all your CSS in the same place.  That makes it easy.  If you're not familiar with enqueuing etc., I would suggest you read up on a bit to understand the concept.  Will help you in a lot of other areas similar to this.  

In this case, if you use my first solution, it should work for you.  Just add any other CSS you have within the <style></style> tags.